# What is the recommended way to nest views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to know what is the recommaned way of nesting Backbone Views.

Possible ways to nest views:

1. Render all views and put them together in the Router
2. Let an IndexView do all the nesting which is called in the router
3. Include views in underscore templates

I tried my luck already in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m48Nc/2/

*Annotation*: I know that the example doesn't work it just shows the structure, I figured out currently, but am not happy about it.

So which way is to go? Links are also welcome ;)

**UPDATE:**

Using fguillen answers and another thread I found we can do:

```
var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    className: "container",

    template: LayoutTemplate,

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(LayoutTemplate);

        this.$('div.content').html(ContentTemplate);
        this.$('div.sidebar').append(new LoginView().render().el);
        this.$('div.sidebar').append(new RegistrationView().render().el);

        return this;
    }

});
```

Comment: One technique outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624917/backbone-js-rendering-creating-multiple-models-within-other-models/11625133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using templates for dynamically append very complex elements one into each other. Templates are meant to dynamically append very simple Model.attributes.

I won't use a *template* for your MenuView. I'll define the Menu frame as a normal element into the HTML DOM and instantiate the MenuView assigning this DOM element to the `View.el` like this:

```
var menuView = new MenuView({ el: "#menu" });
```

Then for render subViews into the MenuView I'll use jQuery `append`, `html` and more *manipulation* jQuery functionalities:

```
// code simplified and not tested
var MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){
    // the this.$el is already rendered

    // list of elements
    this.collection.each( function( model ){
      var modelView = new ModelView({ model: model });
      this.$el.append( modelView.render().el );
    }, this);

    // additional subViews
    var loginView = new LoginView();
    this.$el.find( "div#login" ).html( loginView.render().el );

    // another way to add subViews
    var loginView = new LoginView({ el: this.$el.find( "div#login" ) });
    loginView.render();
  }
});
```

Comment: Is Backbone.Collection.View part of your own libs?

Comment: Based on the lack of lib-specific code in that render function, it might just be included in the "typo" module :^)

Comment: The thing is that your solution matches already mine to a big part. What boathers me is the different views together in such a ViewCollecion: Layout, Lists, Items, some 3rd-party view. That are 3-4 different view types which partly require a special order.

Comment: your this.$el won't reference the right this.  You need to save it before you got into the .each function.

Comment: @bluedevil2k right! I have added `this` as a second parameter to the `each` function.

Comment: @kyogron I have updated the answer to offer more `SubView` rendering systems.

Comment: Thank you :) I found that we also can use this.$('div.content) maybe this helps you :)

Comment: I edited the answer to use the short version of this.find, reference here: http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar

Comment: @DanielAranda the _edit_ has been rejected by others http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/329574 I don't have strong opinion about this so I let it like it is. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: @fguillen no worries fguillen, may be is a rule that I was not aware, looks like when you edit a post you cannot comment about it on the post. So, my technical suggestion is ok, just was not accepted because it. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#view_patterns

They have great examples for how to structure your views based on your needs.